# Sacar valores de input en formularios JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

No consigo ver los resultados que escribo en los campos del formulario, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma pero no me saca tanto lo introducido en el campo de usuario ni en el campo de contraseña.

```js
function contrasena() {

  //HTML

  document.getElementById("cuerpoCentral").innerHTML =

    '<form id="formLogin">' +
    "Usuario:" + '<br>' +
    '<input id="user" type="text" name="username">' + '<br>' + '<br>' + 'Contraseña:' + '<br>' +
    '<input id="pass" type="password" name="pass">' + '<br>' +
    '</form>' + '<br>' +
    '<button onclick="contrasena()">' + 'Comprobar' + '</button>';

  //JS

  var myInput = document.getElementById("user");
  var myInput2 = document.getElementById("pass");

  alert(myInput.value);
  alert(myInput2.value);

  alert(myInput.value.length);
  alert(myInput2.value.length);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="contrasena.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="cuerpoCentral">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tal como pones tu codigo, nunca va a mandar llamar el innerHTML por que la funcion contrasena nunca se manda llamar porque usas esa funcion para crear el boton que va a llamar la funcion, saca el innerhtml de la funcion y dejalo en el load de la pagina y prueba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas sacar el `innerHtml` de tu función para que así se cree primero el `form` que contiene el botón y después al dar click al botón podrá ejecutarse la función, algo así:

```html
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="cuerpoCentral">
  </div>
</body>
<script>
 document.getElementById("cuerpoCentral").innerHTML =

    '<form id="formLogin">' +
    "Usuario:" + '<br>' +
    '<input id="user" type="text" name="username">' + '<br>' + '<br>' + 'Contraseña:' + '<br>' +
    '<input id="pass" type="password" name="pass">' + '<br>' +
    '</form>' + '<br>' +
    '<button onclick="contrasena()">' + 'Comprobar' + '</button>';
    
    function contrasena() {

  var myInput = document.getElementById("user");
  var myInput2 = document.getElementById("pass");

  alert(myInput.value);
  alert(myInput2.value);

  alert(myInput.value.length);
  alert(myInput2.value.length);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Ademas que necesitas poner tu `javascript` al final de tu `html` para que termine de cargar todo, y así detecte el `div` y cree el `form` en base al mismo.